# Spring roo limitations

Tags: roo

I want to start developing enterprise grade applications using spring stack.

to increase the productivity and to compete in the market, I would like to use RAD tools. I found spring roo, but for me, it looks like, it is suitable only to build simple crud based applications. Not suitable to build applications with custom UI. Can you please let me know, can we build any enterprise grade application using ROO or it is not suitable for enterprise grade applications.